# There are no commands defined in the "shopify-app:make" namespace

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a Webhook Job in laravel for an app for merchants on Shopify. When i run the command

```
php artisan shopify-app:make:webhook OrdersCreateJob orders/create,
```

it is suppose to create a webhook job file in 
 `App/Jobs/OrdersCreateJob.php` but i get the error

> > There are no commands defined in the "shopify-app:make" namespace.
> >
> > Did you mean this?
> >           shopify-app

**App/Console/Kernel.php**

```
    protected $commands = [
        //
       Commands\WebhookJob::class,

    ];    

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
            $schedule->command('shopify-app:make')->hourly();

    }
```

**WebhookJob**

```
 protected $signature = 'shopify-app:make';
```

What am i not doing right ? Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your command is in the wrong folder. It should be in the `app/console/Commands` folder

Comment: There is not Commands folder in that Path